# Unable to install laravel using composer "composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel blog"

Tags: laravel, composer-php

Installing laravel/laravel (v5.7.13)
  - Installing laravel/laravel (v5.7.13): Downloading (failed)
Downloading (failed)
Downloading (failed)    Failed to download laravel/laravel from dist: The "https://api.github.com/repos/laravel/laravel/zipball/c09519f547ae7a97eb26433f159cd81b8753e666" file could not be downloaded: SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
error:1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed
Failed to enable crypto
failed to open stream: operation failed
    Now trying to download from source
  - Installing laravel/laravel (v5.7.13): Cloning c09519f547

[RuntimeException]
  Failed to clone https://github.com/laravel/laravel.git, git was not found, check that it is installed and in your P
  ATH env.

'git' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
  operable program or batch file.

create-project [-s|--stability STABILITY] [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--repository REPOSITORY] [--repository-url REPOSITORY-URL] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [--no-secure-http] [--keep-vcs] [--remove-vcs] [--no-install] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--] [] [] []

Comment: you may be fixed by turning off TLS for Composer, it's not safe though.by using command  `composer config -g -- disable-tls true`

Comment: still getting error after running  "composer config -g -- disable-tls true"  this command

Comment: **git was not found**. Do you have git installed?